# How to make Bootstrap arrow displays properly on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Ruby on Rails with assets pipeline + Bootstrap 3.
I want to display arrow using markup below:

```
.row.displayarrowsdown
  %h2.glyphicon.glyphicon-arrow-down{:type => "button", :class => "btn btn-default"}
```

When it works properly on the development machine, on production it doesn't.

Please take a look at attachments (first is correct, from development, the second sucks).

[image: glyphicon on development machine]
[image: glyphicon on production machine]

How to deal with this mismatch ?

Comment: did you run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` before starting your server?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the **icon font** file is missing and the default font has been used; default font obviously has other symbols in respective places.

Issues like that can be looked up in Chrome Developer Tools (F12) and the likes, look for any 404 errors – that's something that shouldn't normally happen in neither development nor production.

This could be related to asset pipeline. Assuming you have your environment variable `RAILS_ENV` set to `production` Run

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Or, depending on your setup:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

If the variable is not there, prepend those with:

```
RAILS_ENV=production OneOfTheAboveCommands
```